# USB drive stop working after making bootable

Tags: usb, bootable-media, hardware-detection

After making my USB drive bootable using WinToFlash, it has stopped working. My laptop now cannot detect the USB.

Comment: TROUBLESHOOTING

Answer (score 0):

You should try reformatting your USB key. I would recommend using the HP USB Disk Storage Format Tool, which you can download [here](http://download.cnet.com/HP-USB-Disk-Storage-Format-Tool/3000-2094_4-10974082.html)